# Polynomial Quantum Algorithm for Graph Isomorphism?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing, np

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NP-intermediate problems with efficient quantum solutions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/np-intermediate-problems-with-efficient-quantum-solutions)

Many suspect that quantum computers will not be able to efficiently solve **NP-complete** problems and  thus focus on the class **NPI**. Among the problems regarded as likely canditates to be in **NPI** are factoring and graph isomorphism. Known yet Shor's algorithm for efficient factorization, what steps have been done towards the design of a polynomial algorithm for graph isomorphism?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3888/4896. also Peter Shor's answer answers your question

Comment: GI reduces to the hidden subgroup problem over symmetric group. Quantum polynomial time algorithms are known for any abelian group. However the symmetric group case is still open.